# Find files in current working directory. This command not working within shell script

Tags: shell

The below script helps to check ssh access to current user and also find files in the current working directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo "Provide input file containing list of machine names"
elif [ -f $1 ]
then
    for host in $(cat $1)
    do
      status=$(ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 $host echo ok 2>&1) # successful ssh prints ok in the status variable
      # echo $status
      if [ "$status" == "ok" ]
      then
        echo "In"
         result=$(find /home/hkc -name "findme.txt") # Command not working from script, whereas its working from command prompt
        # result=$(find . -print | grep -i findme)
        echo $result
      else
        echo $status
      fi
    done
else
   echo "File not found"
fi
```

**expected o/p:**

```
find . -name "find*"

./findme.txt
./find.txt
```

**actual o/p:**

```
hkc@client ~]$ ./ssh_access.sh machine_names.txt 

In
find: ‘/home/hkc/Downloads/copy_docu/newdir3’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/hkc/Downloads/copy_docu/newdir4’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/hkc/Downloads/copy_docu/tmp’: Permission denied
```

The command is not able to find the files. Please help me to find the error.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Harita! Are you sure your `echo $result` doesn't display anything at the end of the error messages? Is your "expected o/p" executed by user hkc in `/home/hkc`?

Comment: Do you still have a problem when you make a small script
`result=$(find /home/hkc -name "findme.txt") ; echo "${result}"`

Comment: @xhienne sadly yes, echo $result doesn't display anything at end of result. The o/p is executed by user hkc in /home/hkc.

Comment: @WalterA yes, still the same problem.

Comment: @harita Do you expect the command `find /home/hkc -name "findme.txt"` to be executed on the remote machine (`$host`)? I don't understand why you execute `find` on the local host, especially inside the `for` loop: `$result` won't change from one host to another.

Comment: @xhienne. I want the find command to find the files on remote host connected via ssh for the same user. So when I ssh to remote host and use find cmd to search the files its working but the same cmd in not working from shell script

Comment: You write that the `find` works on the remote host, but your script performs tthe `find` on the local host. Try `find /home/hkc -name "findme.txt"` pn the local host without `ssh`, I think you will see the error messages..

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a `/home/hkc` on your local machine as well as on your remote machine. You expect your `find /home/hkc -name "findme.txt"` to be executed on the remote host but actually, it doesn't, it is executed on your local machine.

In your code, your ssh session actually started and ended with this line:

```
status=$(ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 $host echo ok 2>&1)
```

The next line (`if ...`) is still processed by your local script.

So, I suggest you change:

```
result=$(find /home/hkc -name "findme.txt")
```

with:

```
result=$(ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 "$host" "find /home/hkc -name findme.txt" 2>&1)
```

(BTW, unless you know what you are doing, always quote your variables! => `"$host"`, not `$host`)

Comment: oops!, I didn't really check that. Thanks a lot. I made the correction its working fine now.

Comment: Glad for you, @Harita! Don't hesitate to accept the answer, then.